# python numpy argsort issue

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

First I generated a random 1d array `x`,
then I generated array `y` by swapping elements of `x`.

Now  `y` is a permutation of `x`, in principle, if
I apply numpy argsort, I should get different results, as it turned out,
it was not the case.

Here are my python codes,

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(10)
print(x)
y = x
y[0], y[1] = x[1], x[0]
y[3], y[4] = x[4], x[3]
print(y)
```

Then I got

```
[ 0.818  0.99   0.291  0.608  0.773  0.232  0.041  0.136  0.645  0.94 ]
[ 0.99   0.818  0.291  0.773  0.608  0.232  0.041  0.136  0.645  0.94 ]
```

Now

```
print(np.argsort(x))
print(np.argsort(y))
```

I got

```
[6 7 5 2 4 8 3 1 9 0]
[6 7 5 2 4 8 3 1 9 0]
```

Comment: `y = x[:]` should work

Comment: @Arman Thanks but `y = x[:]` is the same as `y=x`

Comment: `y = x[:]` is like`y = x.copy()`

Comment: @Arman I'm using python3, it might work on other versions of python. BTW x is a numpy array not a list.

Comment: it's work on Python 3.x too

Comment: @Arman -- I'm not sure about that.  First, `x[:]` will only have a chance at working for 1D arrays.  Second, `x[:]` creates a view in numpy.  I think that this _can_ create a copy under some circumstances, but it frequently doesn't. . .

Comment: I nominated this for re-opening because the dupe question specifically dealt with lists when OP is working with numpy arrays.  The behavior in this regard is certainly different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
y = x
```

You *alias* `y` and `x`.  They're the same object which you can see by issuing the following statement

```
y is x  # True
```

Instead, you probably want:

```
y = x.copy()
```

Comment: Thanks! `y = x` and `y = x[:]` do NOT work; `y is x` and `y = x.copy()` both work.